# Can a function have a set of functions as domain and codomain?

Tags: functions, set-theory

This question is simple. Using the ZF axioms, i might try to define a set as
$$F= \\{ x|x\text{ is a function} \\}$$
If that is the case, i can effectively define a function $α:F\rightarrow F$. This means that $α$ would take functions as inputs and outputs. The question is, is this set possible in ZF axioms? If so, what could be the universal set? Can $α$ exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is that $F$ cannot exist as a set.  It is a proper class.  If $F$ were a set, then the set of all domains of elements of $F$ would exist, and that set would be a universal set, which we know can't exist.